# Dynamically changing apache proxypass config (scripting httpd.conf?)

Tags: php, apache, proxy, httpd.conf

Background on the scenario:

Our CI system deploys multiple VM's, each with unique (though temporary) IPs.  I have an apache proxy set up on the front to provide clean URL's to these VM's so that the various users don't have to remember IP's that can sometimes switch multiple times a day.

The problem is... I don't want to keep having to manually edit my httpd.conf file to change the IP's that the url's map to.

I know I could use PHP to edit the httpd.conf file, and probably restart apache.  This seems like an anti-pattern to me.  What is the better way to do this?  Can Apache read the proxypass settings from a seperate file?